# LXD, apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match"

Tags: apparmor

How can I solve this **apparmor** issue? This **apparmor** message appears every 30 minutes in my log.

`dmesg` output:

```
...
[5535381.853068] audit: type=1400 audit(1546688340.298:866): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxd-wiki_</var/lib/lxd>" name="/home/" pid=26891 comm="(ionclean)" flags="ro, nosuid, nodev, remount, bind"
[5537181.860921] audit: type=1400 audit(1546690140.303:867): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxd-wiki_</var/lib/lxd>" name="/home/" pid=27570 comm="(ionclean)" flags="ro, nosuid, nodev, remount, bind"
[5538981.929133] audit: type=1400 audit(1546691940.298:868): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxd-wiki_</var/lib/lxd>" name="/home/" pid=29211 comm="(ionclean)" flags="ro, nosuid, nodev, remount, bind"
```

My system is a **Ubuntu Server 18.04** and there is a LXD container (name of the container: `wiki`, Ubuntu 18.04, Apache Webserver + PHP) running.

- lxd 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
- Linux 4.15.0-38-generic

I already tried to edit the **apparmor** configuration (`/etc/apparmor.d/lxc/lxc-default`). I added this:

```
  mount options=(rw, bind, ro),
```

After my configuration change I reloaded the config:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

The messages still appearing in my log. I also tried this:

```
  mount options=(ro, nosuid, nodev, remount, bind),
```

Or is there a way to hide these messages?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find this? [apparmor=“DENIED” operation=“mount”](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/apparmor-denied-operation-mount/2424/4) The suggestion there is that it [Seems to be caused by the PHP cron job to clear old sessions, but I don’t see where that job is attempting to remount /home.](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/apparmor-denied-operation-mount/2424/6)

Comment: Thanks! But how can I fix this?

Comment: Two years later, the links provided by @steeldriver have reached a better resolution. See https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/apparmor-denied-operation-mount/2424/18, and https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/what-does-security-nesting-true/7156/2 for explanation.